# Convert eregi_replace

Tags: preg-replace

I migrated to a new PHP Version. Now I have lots of eregi_replace statements throwning errors:

```
$text = eregi_replace("([ \r\n])http://([^ ,\r\n]*)","\\1[url]http://\\2[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("([ \r\n])https://([^ ,\r\n]*)","\\1[url]https://\\2[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("([ \r\n])ftp://([^ ,\r\n]*)","\\1[url]ftp://\\2[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("([ \r\n])www.([^ ,\r\n]*)","\\1[url]http://www.\\2[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("^http://([^ ,\r\n]*)","[url]http://\\1[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("^https://([^ ,\r\n]*)","[url]https://\\1[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("^ftp://([^ ,\r\n]*)","[url]ftp://\\1[/url]", $text);
$text = eregi_replace("^www.([^ ,\r\n]*)","[url]http://www.\\1[/url]", $text);
```

I know I have to use preg_replace. As another person wrote this code I have no clue how to achive this. Maybe someone can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the equivalent of the first eregi_replace you have

```
$text = preg_replace("#([ \r\n])http://([^ ,\r\n]*)#i","$1[url]http://$2[/url]", $text);
```

generalized that would mean:

```
$text = preg_replace('#'.$yourCurrentRegexString.'#i',str_replace('\\','$',$yourCurrentReplacement), $text);
```